# php: usage of define

Tags: php

in Yii they use this code:

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

i've never seen anyone write like this before (or). is this real php code or some syntax of yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to short circuit evaluation.

If `defined('YII_DEBUG')` returns `false`, it will try to evaluate the second expression to make the sentence true, defining `YII_DEBUG` constant as `true`.

The final result is that, if the constant were not defined, then define it as being `true`. If it's already defined (the value doesn't matter), then do nothing (as the first expression is true, the second expression does not need to be evaluated for the expression to be true).

Answer (score 5):

Basically if `defined("YII_DEBUG")` evaluates to false, it will then define it. Kinda like:

`mysql_connect() or die("DIE!!!!!");`

It is actual PHP syntax, just not commonly used. It allows you to not have to write:

```
if(!defined("YII_DEBUG"))
{
    define("YII_DEBUG", true);
}
```

or even shorter

```
if(!defined("YII_DEBUG"))
    define("YII_DEBUG", true);
```

I'm guessing they used it to get rid of the if statement altogether. The second if statement without brackets would be a hazard for editing, and the first one might have taken up too much room for the developer.

Personally, I'd stick clear of this just because it isn't a commonly known feature. By using commonly known syntaxes (the if statements), other programmers don't have to wonder what it does.

(Although, I might now that I look at it. Seems straightforward and gets rid of unnessecary if clauses)

Comment: It looks like nice clean code. I can see myself using this syntax somewhere in the future.

Comment: i have also seen defined(CONSTANT) ? null : define('CONSTANT', true);

that is also very clean

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward - the 'or' operator is efficient in that it will only evaluate the second part of the statement if it needs to. So if the first part evaluates to true (the constant is already defined), then the define() call isn't executed.